# Haskell bind socket to specific IP

Tags: haskell, ip, ip-address, endianness

In the Haskell `network` package

`bindSocket` uses `HostAddress` and `HostAddress6`

which are defined as:

```
-- | Network byte order.
type HostAddress = Word32

-- | Host byte order.
type HostAddress6 = (Word32, Word32, Word32, Word32)
```

- How can I go from `123.123.123.123` to a `Word32`?
- How can I go from an `IPv6` string to `(Word32, Word32, Word32, Word32)`?
- Does endianness play a role on different OSes (Windows, Linux, OS X, FreeBSD)?

Comment: It looks like the [network-address](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-address) package addresses some of these conversions.

Comment: @DanielWagner `network-address` (`readpIPv4`, 0.1.0.0 -> 65535) is inconsistent with `Network.BSD` (`getHostByName`, 0.1.0.0 -> 256). I also do not like how wordy it is. The app I want to use it in is 378 lines itself o__O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`getAddrInfo`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/network/2.3.0.11/doc/html/Network-Socket.html#v:getAddrInfo):

```
getAddrInfo :: Maybe AddrInfo -> Maybe HostName -> Maybe ServiceName -> IO [AddrInfo]
```

> Resolve a host or service name to one or more addresses. The AddrInfo values that this function returns contain SockAddr values that you can pass directly to connect or bindSocket.
>
> This function is protocol independent. It can return both IPv4 and IPv6 address information.

Comment: `Prelude Network.Socket> getAddrInfo Nothing (Just "127.0.0.1") Nothing`
`*** Exception: getAddrInfo: does not exist (error 10093)`

Comment: Sorry, the error was due to me forgetting `withSocketsDo`. This seems to work with all kinds of IP address strings in a truly cross-platform way with lots of extra information :)